# Disable updates in Firefox ESR

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to, on install, disable update checking and prevent Firefox from installing updates? We intend to install updates in a controlled manner using SCCM. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question, but nowadays (65.0.2) disabling updates is relatively complicated. Here's the solution:

1. In the firefox application directory, create a directory named **distribution**.  On Windows, create a directory called `distribution` where the EXE is located. On Mac, the location is `Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/distribution`. On Linux, the location is `firefox/distribution`, where `firefox` is the installation directory for firefox, which varies by distribution, but is often `/opt/firefox`.
2. Inside **distribution**, place a filed named **policies.json** containing the following:

   ```
   {
       "policies": {
           "DisableAppUpdate": true
       }
   }
   ```

Sources:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1232918

https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md

Note: I can only vouch for the Windows solution because I have tried it and it worked. The others are imported from the links.

Comment: Unfortunately this method won’t work on macOS, as adding this file in the app bundle will break code signing of the Firefox app, causing macOS to refuse launching the app.

Comment: Oh, I have borrowed a MacBook for studies and Firefox is broken in several ways. I'm not even trying to fix it. Sorry this didn't work. :(

Comment: Yeah no worries, I just wanted to note this here for others who might read this.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your automatic installation setting by using this

> Tools -> Options -> Advance -> Update

and change the option according to your purpose.
The above only affects your own account.
To do it for all, you can place a file the file "local-settings.js" in the `defaults\pref` folder to specify `mozilla.cfg`.

http://www.geo-tux.de/it/firefox-10-esr-deployment

Comment: This race condition, To stop update. Lunch the application and change the option before it automatically update

Answer (score 2):

Put an exclusion for the Firefox update site in /etc/hosts, or block that site at your firewall.  Then none of the machines will be able to get to it at all and you can deploy updates as you wish.

Bring up Firefox, go to about:config and check the contents of "app.update.url".  Then block that site / IP address.  I suspect that Mozilla rotates IP addresses on that FQDN so blocking it by IP address might be a bit tricky.  Easier to block it in /etc/hosts, though you would need to push a hosts file to every system.

At present the update server appears to be "aus5.mozilla.org" (both from the Mozilla discussion at the link below, and from my own browser) but this could change (a) according to region or (b) with the next release.

See also:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1224757

Comment: Great answer. I just went to about:config and deleted the value of the "app.update.url"